Upgrade mongoose Version to latest
we are panning to upgrade our mongoose version from 5.12.0 to V8.4.1, our Mongo DB is V6.0.11. I understand that there are breaking changes related to callback and no more warning which we have taken care already.
Documentation suggests first go from 5x to 6x then 6x to 7x and 7x to 8x. which is very long and tedious as we have many services. I have gone through below links
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#version-requirements https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_8.html
I do not see anything related to schema update.
also tried finding error anyone has encountered.
If anyone has encountered issue during version upgrade?
Should I go step by step as suggested in documentation or I can go directly and face music in production.
Additionally:
I am using this const conn = mongoose.createConnection(uri); instead of
await mongoose.createConnection(uri).asPromise(); is there any difference other than synchronous and asynchronous calls?
reason: I have requirement to create multiple database connection with 1 service.
